# how to use access token to create a new user account using google provisioning api in .net

Tags: oauth2-playground

I am trying to create a dektop application to create new user account into particular user group using Provisioning API of google.

I am using some >Net libraries in my code , here is how my code looks like.

```
string token = GetNewAuthenticationToken("domain.name", "adminEmail", "adminPassword");
AppsService service = new AppsService("domain.name", token);
service.CreateUser("usernametest", "userfirstname", "userlastname","userpasswordtest12345");
```

But I am getting this error, 
*Execution of request failed*: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain.name/user/2.0

I know it has something to do with token I am getting, can anybody have any idea on how to pass the token with *service.createuser* method?

And also what is use of that client id and client secret code which is generated while registering app on google.